# Simplify Grunt Compression of static assets

Tags: nginx, gruntjs, gzip, brotli

I am pre-compressing static assets (for example style.css) in my Grunt build process using Gzip (style.css.gz) and Brotli (style.css.br). Because I couldn't find a better tutorial or examples, I added a compress task with dozens of sub-tasks for each and every extension I want to compress. This is for use with Nginx' `gzip_static on;` and `brotli_static on;` directives.

What I have so far:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'compress:jsgz',
        'compress:jsbr',
        'compress:cssgz',
        'compress:cssbr',
        'compress:mapgz',
        'compress:mapbr',
        'compress:ttfgz',
        'compress:ttfbr',
        'compress:eotgz',
        'compress:eotbr',
        'compress:otfgz',
        'compress:otfbr',
        'compress:svggz',
        'compress:svgbr',
        'compress:woffgz',
        'compress:woffbr',
        'compress:woff2gz'
        'compress:woff2br'
        ...
```

an example sub-task looks like this:

```
compress: {
          jsgz: {
            options: {
              mode: 'gzip',
              level: 6
            },
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'wordpress/',
            dest: 'wordpress/',
            extDot: 'last',
            src: ['**/*.js'],
            ext: '.js.gz'
          },
          ...
```

While this works just fine, I would actually prefer having only 2 sub-tasks one for gzip one for brotli:

```
gzip: {
    options: {
      mode: 'gzip',
      level: 6
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'wordpress/',
    dest: 'wordpress/',
    extDot: 'last',
    src: ['**/*.(js|css|map|ttf|eot|otf|svg|woff|woof2|xml|txt|...)'],
    ext: '.???.gz'
},
brotli: {...}
```

Does the ext parameter allow a placeholder? Something dynamic?
Can I achieve that somehow? Thanks for your help.